# Lerna package import in CI

Tags: typescript, jestjs, continuous-integration, bundling-and-minification, lerna

I want to test my typescript library.
It has two parts: core and client. `client` instance `core` to use its functions.

```js
import { Core } from "@lib/core";
class Client {
  constructor() {
    new Core();
  }
}
```

To make these two parts independent, I use `lerna` as if they were separated npm packages: `@lib/core` and `@lib/client`.

Everything runs ok in local environment, but in gitlab CI this error is thrown before the client tests start:

```
Cannot find module '@lib/core' from 'src/lib/client.spec.ts'
      3 |
    > 4 | jest.mock('@lib/core');
        |      ^
```

**lerna.json**

```json
{
  "packages": ["packages/core", "packages/client"],
  "version": "independent",
  "npmClient": "npm"
}
```

**`.gitlab-ci.yml`**

```yaml
image: node:14

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules
    - '**/node_modules'
    - .npm
    - dist

---
unit:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npx jest --clear-cache
    - npm run test
```

---

Inside `packages/client` I have a node_modules folder with a symlink to `@lib/core`.

```
packages
├── client
│   ├── ng-package.json
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── @lib
│   │       └── core -> ../../../core
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       ├── lib
│       │   ├── client.ts
│       └── public-api.ts
└── core
    ├── ng-package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    └── src
        ├── lib
        │   ├── core.ts
        └── public-api.ts
```

When the code is compiled, in `dist` folder there are the two libraries (client, core). Inside the compiled code of client, the reference to core is like this: `require('@lib/core')`.

In local environment it works because I have these paths in tsconfig:

```
"paths": {
      "@lib/core": ["dist/core"],
      "@lib/client": ["dist/client"]
}
```

In ci it tries to download lib/core from the registry and it does not exist.

I would like to make `client` import `core` code and provide only one library (all together). So the import of `core` is transparent to the final user.

Comment: Running `lerna bootstrap` will create the symlink I think

Comment: It does, but the test seems to not be aware of that

Comment: Do you have a `"workspaces": [ "packages/*" ]` in the top-level package.json?

Comment: Didn't have it. Throws the same error after adding it :(